# Include an external JavaScript file as-is in Angular dist folder

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an external npm module that looks for a specific file in the app's root directory (in the case of Angular, the `dist/` folder). A relatively simple solution is to put that file there. However, I don't know of a way to do it: putting the path to the file in `angular.json` under `scripts` simply includes the script in `main.js`. Putting it under assets wouldn't solve this specific case either.

Is it possible to configure the built to include it in the `dist` folder as-is? (Angular 8)

Comment: In assets (in angular.json) you can also copy to the root. Doesn’t have to be inside the assets folder..?

Comment: @MikeOne thanks I thought of doing that, but is there a way to map the asset to the root path in dist? Including the original asset in the root folder just to have it in the correct dir seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: it looks like it's actually possible to specify assets not just as individual entries, but also as objects. It's actually in the documentation but I had previously missed it: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config

Therefore, the assets can look like:

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets",
    "src/favicon.ico"
]
```

But also something like this:

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets",
    "src/favicon.ico",
    {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "path/to/my/custom/asset/dir/",
        "output": "/"
    }
]
```

This allows the mapping of an individual asset to an output path.

Comment: Exactly. Great you found it.